# Can Keras' model.predict return a dictionary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The documentation https://keras.io/models/model/#predict says that  `model.predict` returns Numpy array(s) of predictions.  **In the Keras API, is there is a way to distinguishing which of these arrays are which?**  How about in the TF implementation?

At the top of the same page of documentation, they say that "models can specify multiple inputs and outputs using lists".  It seems that nothing breaks if instead, one passes dictionaries:

```
my_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=my_inputs_dict, outputs=my_outputs_dict)
```

When calling `model.fit` the same documentation says "If input layers in the model are named, you can also pass a dictionary mapping input names to Numpy arrays."

It would be nice if either the keys from `my_output_dict` or the names of the dictionary values (layers) in `my_output_dict` were attached to the outputs of `my_model.predict(...)`

If I save the model to TensorFlow's saved_model format protobuf using 
 `tf.keras.model.save` the tf.serving API works this way-- with named inputs and outputs...

Comment: I suspect that the answer may just be " use lists, not dictionaries in your model definition and the outputs will have the same ordering as in the model definition."  If this is the case, I would think that passing dictionaries for input and output should raise an exception, unless there is an implicit reliance on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744

Comment: When I try passing a dictionary to the `outputs` argument, I get the following exception: `ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras 'Layer'`. I agree that, if this option is not documented, it should throw an exception as otherwise the outputs would have an arbitrary order.

Comment: @rvinas which keras version are you using?  I've tried with both tf.keras for 2.0.0-beta1 and 1.14 and neither throws an exception.

Comment: I am using keras 2.2.4

Comment: Tensorflow.keras has an example of `dict` as both input and output of `model.fit()`: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#passing_data_to_multi-input_multi-output_models. Nothing about `model.predict()`, sadly. I would also prefer it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `my_model.output_names`

Given

```py
my_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=my_inputs_dict, outputs=my_outputs_dict)
```

create the `dict` yourself from `my_model.output_names`, which is a list of `name` attributes of your output layers in the order of prediction

```py
prediction_list = my_model.predict(my_test_input_dict)
prediction_dict = {name: pred for name, pred in zip(my_model.output_names, prediction_list)}
```