# What is the order of the elements in the list returned by Keras' model.predict in the case of multiple outputs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

In the case of multiple outputs, `model.predict` returns a list. What does the order of the elements in this list correspond to? For example, in the case, you have a different loss for each of the outputs that you specify as a dictionary (and recall that dictionaries do not necessarily maintain any order of their elements)? What about in the case you specify these losses as a list? What about if the losses are all the same? There's a related Stack Overflow question [Can Keras' model.predict return a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57277926/3924118) and [Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2422). Maybe the Keras' documentation should be improved. This is currently not documented anywhere, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The outputs of your model are defined when you make the model instance using `Model(inputs=[...], outputs=[...])`, and `model.predict` will provide outputs in the same order.

This is implicitly documented in the [Model class](https://keras.io/models/model/), where it says:

> In the case of multi-input or multi-output models, you can use lists as well:

Since lists are ordered, it can be assumed that the outputs of `model.predict` are in the same order as the model was defined.

Comment: Well, of course, I was expecting this to be the case, for any reasonable API, but you can pass a lot of stuff to outputs (including dictionaries?), so, unless this is documented somewhere, I think people should be careful when designing their models, in order not to get unexpected outputs. It would be nice if you provided a link to the documentation or implementation that shows that this is really the case.

Comment: @nbro No, you can't create a model using a dictionary, nowhere it is said to be supported, the documentation mentions lists (see updated answer). For fit and compile you can pass dictionaries mapping output names and loss/data, but that does not change the model definition.

Comment: You can pass a dictionary to the `outputs` parameter of the `Model` class. I've just checked it.

Comment: @nbro I just tried in Keras 2.3.1 and it gives an error when you use a dictionary for the outputs parameter: ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: {'foo': <tf.Tensor 'a/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, 'bar': <tf.Tensor 'b/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>}

Comment: Please, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nbro/30832c777b6ae6c67b980abb1bd74ea4).

Comment: @nbro Your gist uses tf.keras, I used keras, this is why I explicitly mentioned which version of Keras I am using. tf.keras and keras are not the same library.